# Unable to connect R and PHP in Windows?

Tags: php, r, rstudio, rscript

I have connected **R** and **php** by using the below command in **Ubuntu**

```
exec("Rscript my_rscript.R  $N", $response);
```

But i cant able to connect these in Windows.

**R installation path is**

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin
```

**R file path is**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\tracker\exec_r.R
```

This is my PHP code:

```
        <?php 
                // poorman.php 
                echo "<form action='poorman.php' method='get'>"; 
                echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />"; 
                echo "<input type='submit' />"; 
                echo "</form>"; if(isset($_GET['N'])) { 
                    $N = $_GET['N']; 
                    exec("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin C:\xampp\htdocs\tracker\exec_r.R $N", $response); 
                    $str = $response[0]; 
                    $myobj = json_decode($str); 
                    echo $myobj->first_name[0]; 
                } 
        ?>
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin` looks like the name of a directory, not an 'R' executable

Comment: Print out the value of $N before the exec() line

Comment: Run the command line on its own in a command window, without using PHP and confirm that it works

Comment: print_r($response) after the exec line

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
exec("C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.3.1\bin C:\xampp\htdocs\tracker\exec_r.R $N", $response);
```

Comment: I have this error -   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Server_R_master\poorman.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Server_R_master\poorman.php on line 16

Comment: Post the source code in your main question, with appropriate markup.

Comment: yeah now i post it in main question,can you help me